# BeagleBone Black Boot Failed with USER2 LED solid on

Tags: boot, beagleboneblack

I am trying to boot a BeagleBone Black with a microSD. I push the boot button and then power up the board and release the button. The user LEDs start blinking but stop after 1 second and only the USER2 LED stays solid. I can't figure out why?

-- Update: I was using a custom image and The image was not compatible with the Beaglebone. I rebuilt the image and it was Ok.

Answer (score 0):

This means something failed in the boot process.

You have two possibilities at this point:

1. Attach a USB-to-UART converter to the debug UART port and look at the actual failure messages
2. Try a different image, different SD-card, rewrite your image to the card, make sure you wrote it correctly

You haven't specified any details about the image you're trying to boot, so it's impossible to go into further details.

Comment: I was using a custom image. I had to rebuild it and it was Ok then.